# error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pprint (from -r requirements.txt (line 67)) (from versions: none)

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, pprint

I am trying to install a NLP suite on my macbook pro, which is updated to the most recent software version Catalina 10.15.6. So far, I have installed Anaconda 3.8, created a version 3.7 NLP environment by `conda create -n NLP python=3.7`, and activated the NLP environment by `conda activate NLP`.

My next step is to install all python packages that are written in the file "requirements.txt" with the following command `pip install -r requirements.txt`. However, it showcases this message:
"*ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pprint (from -r requirements.txt (line 67)) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pprint (from -r requirements.txt (line 67)*)"

I also tried installing the package alone, however, the same error message appears.

Any advice would be appreciated! Please let me know if any additional information I can provide.

Comment: [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) is a built-in module, part of the standard library. It shouldn't be in a `requirements.txt`.

Comment: try importing pprint directly... it is most probably already available.

Comment: @Macindows How do I import pprint directly in terminal?

Comment: @MattDMo Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`pprint` is part of the standard library, therefore cannot be present in `requirements.txt`. If one of your requirements is stated to require pprint you'll get an error. To install without dependencies use the `--no-deps` command for pip. However, this does not guarantee that the installation actually worked as you are likely missing out on other packages. So a better option is installing each requirement one by one until you find the one that needs it and install its other dependencies and install that package with no-deps.

An alternative is to use https://pypi.org/project/pipdeptree/ to inspect the dependency tree.

If there are many packages and there is a version freeze, try dropping the versions.

It is a bit of trial and error detective work, so one can be smart about it: it is likely a less used dependency that is the culprit.

Comment: Strangely enough, I had pprint in requirements.txt for a very long time and it always worked.. only in the past week it started to fail..

Comment: Same. My guess is that there was in pypi a module called `pprint` that has been recently removed as it masked the standard library module, thus revealing cases where `pprint` was in `requirements.txt` either directly or indirectly in a dependency.