# No matching distribution found for pprint

Tags: pip, requirements.txt, pprint

I am trying to install the `requirements.txt` file for `skiptracer` and it keeps saying

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pprint (from -r requirements.txt (line 7)) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pprint (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
```

I can't even install `pprint`

Comment: After looking at the [xillwillx/skiptracer](https://github.com/xillwillx/skiptracer) package, it seems that it can easily be installed with `pip install -e ./` as it has a `setup.py`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pprint (from -r requirements.txt (line 67)) (from versions: none)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63457762/error-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-pprint-from-r-r)

Answer (score 12):

`pprint` is a [Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/pprint.html) module. That is, it comes bundled with python.

You can just `import pprint` in a python script without pip installing it.

To solve your issue, delete line 20 `pprint=0.1` of your [requirements.txt](https://github.com/xillwillx/skiptracer/blob/master/requirements.txt)

Comment: I removed the pprint and it installed all the other requirements but now when i tried to run python3 skiptracer.py i get the following messageTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "skiptracer.py", line 4, in <module>
    from plugins.menus import menus
  File "/home/kali/skiptracer-2.0-beta/plugins/menus.py", line 4, in <module>
    from plugins.banner import Logo
  File "/home/kali/skiptracer-2.0-beta/plugins/banner.py", line 3, in <module>
    from plugins.colors import BodyColors as bc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plugins.colors'   plz hlp

Answer (score 0):

Confirming here that pprint is part of the python standard library, with online documentation presented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html).

As stated in the documentation, pprint can be set to pp such that:

```
from pprint import pprint as pp
```

works as expected.

Answer (score -3):

You may also try to edit requirements.txt and rename `pprint` to `print`

Comment: That won't help.

Answer (score -3):

The command to install pprint is

```
pip install pprintpp
```

I had the same issue, found the answer [here](https://pypi.org/project/pprintpp/)

Comment: That is not correct. [`pprint` is part of Python's standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) and it does not need to be installed. The `pprintpp` you are recommending is something else, not what the question asked for.