# conda create env using yml file - ResolvePackageNotFound error keeps changing

Tags: pip, conda

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. I am trying to use `conda` to create an environment through the `yml` file from this GitHub repository https://github.com/thanard/causal-infogan.

The command is `conda env create -f tf14.yml` and the file `tf14.yml` is described below.

```
name: tf14
channels:
- jjhelmus
- soumith
- menpo
- kne
- defaults
dependencies:
- boto=2.48.0=py35_0
- cffi=1.10.0=py35_0
- click=6.6=py35_0
- cycler=0.10.0=py35_0
- dbus=1.10.10=0
- decorator=4.0.10=py35_0
- entrypoints=0.2.2=py35_0
- expat=2.1.0=0
- flask=0.11.1=py35_0
- fontconfig=2.12.1=3
- freetype=2.5.5=1
- glib=2.43.0=1
- gst-plugins-base=1.8.0=0
- gstreamer=1.8.0=0
- h5py=2.7.0=np112py35_0
- hdf5=1.8.17=1
- icu=54.1=0
- ipykernel=4.5.0=py35_0
- ipython=5.1.0=py35_0
- ipython_genutils=0.1.0=py35_0
- itsdangerous=0.24=py35_0
- jbig=2.1=0
- jinja2=2.8=py35_1
- jpeg=9b=0
- jsonschema=2.5.1=py35_0
- jupyter_client=4.4.0=py35_0
- jupyter_core=4.2.0=py35_0
- libffi=3.2.1=0
- libgcc=5.2.0=0
- libgfortran=3.0.0=1
- libgpuarray=0.6.2=0
- libiconv=1.14=0
- libpng=1.6.27=0
- libsodium=1.0.10=0
- libtiff=4.0.6=3
- libxcb=1.12=0
- libxml2=2.9.2=0
- llvmlite=0.16.0=py35_0
- mako=1.0.4=py35_0
- markupsafe=0.23=py35_2
- matplotlib=2.0.2=np112py35_0
- mistune=0.7.3=py35_0
- mkl=2017.0.1=0
- mkl-service=1.1.2=py35_3
- mock=2.0.0=py35_0
- nbconvert=4.2.0=py35_0
- nbformat=4.1.0=py35_0
- networkx=1.11=py35_0
- nomkl=1.0=0
- notebook=4.2.3=py35_0
- numba=0.31.0=np112py35_0
- numexpr=2.6.2=np112py35_nomkl_0
- numpy=1.12.1=py35_nomkl_0
- olefile=0.44=py35_0
- openblas=0.2.19=0
- openssl=1.0.2j=0
- pandas=0.20.1=np112py35_0
- path.py=8.2.1=py35_0
- pbr=1.10.0=py35_0
- pexpect=4.0.1=py35_0
- pickleshare=0.7.4=py35_0
- pillow=4.2.1=py35_0
- pip=9.0.1=py35_1
- prompt_toolkit=1.0.3=py35_0
- ptyprocess=0.5.1=py35_0
- pycparser=2.18=py35_0
- pygments=2.1.3=py35_0
- pygpu=0.6.2=py35_0
- pyparsing=2.1.4=py35_0
- pyqt=5.6.0=py35_2
- python=3.5.2=0
- python-dateutil=2.5.3=py35_0
- pytz=2016.7=py35_0
- pyzmq=15.4.0=py35_0
- qt=5.6.2=5
- readline=6.2=2
- scikit-learn=0.18.1=np112py35_nomkl_1
- scipy=0.19.0=np112py35_nomkl_0
- seaborn=0.7.1=py35_0
- setuptools=27.2.0=py35_0
- simplegeneric=0.8.1=py35_1
- sip=4.18=py35_0
- six=1.10.0=py35_0
- sqlite=3.13.0=0
- terminado=0.6=py35_0
- tk=8.5.18=0
- tornado=4.4.2=py35_0
- traitlets=4.3.1=py35_0
- wcwidth=0.1.7=py35_0
- werkzeug=0.11.11=py35_0
- wheel=0.29.0=py35_0
- xz=5.2.2=0
- zeromq=4.1.4=0
- zlib=1.2.8=3
- protobuf=3.0.0b2=py35_1
- pybox2d=2.3.1post2=py35_0
- pygame=1.9.2a0=py35_0
- ipywidgets=5.1.5=py35_0
- joblib=0.10.3=py35_0
- opencv3=3.1.0=py35_0
- widgetsnbextension=1.2.3=py35_1
- cuda80=1.0=0
- pytorch=0.2.0=py35hb1547bd_4cu80
- pip:
  - appdirs==1.4.3
  - astar==0.9
  - atari-py==0.1.1
  - awscli==1.11.190
  - azure==1.0.3
  - azure-common==1.1.8
  - azure-mgmt==0.20.2
  - azure-mgmt-common==0.20.0
  - azure-mgmt-compute==0.20.1
  - azure-mgmt-network==0.20.1
  - azure-mgmt-nspkg==2.0.0
  - azure-mgmt-resource==0.20.1
  - azure-mgmt-storage==0.20.0
  - azure-nspkg==2.0.0
  - azure-servicebus==0.20.1
  - azure-servicemanagement-legacy==0.20.2
  - azure-storage==0.20.3
  - bleach==1.5.0
  - boltons==18.0.0
  - boto3==1.4.4
  - botocore==1.7.48
  - box2d==2.3.1
  - box2d-kengz==2.3.3
  - cached-property==1.3.0
  - cloudpickle==0.5.2
  - colorama==0.3.7
  - colored-traceback==0.2.2
  - colorlover==0.2.1
  - cython==0.26.1
  - dill==0.2.7.1
  - docutils==0.14
  - enum34==1.1.6
  - flatbuffers==2015.12.22.1
  - funcsigs==1.0.2
  - glfw==1.4.0
  - gym==0.8.0
  - html5lib==0.9999999
  - imageio==2.2.0
  - ipdb==0.10.3
  - ipython-genutils==0.1.0
  - japronto==0.1.1
  - jmespath==0.9.3
  - jupyter-client==4.4.0
  - jupyter-core==4.2.0
  - keras==2.0.8
  - lasagne==0.1
  - markdown==2.6.11
  - ml-logger==0.0.23
  - moleskin==1.5.1
  - mpi4py==2.0.0
  - mujoco-py==0.5.7
  - opencv-python==3.2.0.6
  - pachi-py==0.0.21
  - packaging==16.8
  - params-proto==2.3.0
  - plotly==2.0.7
  - pprint==0.1
  - progressbar2==3.34.2
  - prompt-toolkit==1.0.3
  - psutil==5.4.3
  - py==1.4.33
  - pyasn1==0.3.7
  - pycairo==1.15.5
  - pyglet==1.2.4
  - pyopengl==3.1.0
  - pyprind==2.10.0
  - pytest==3.0.7
  - python-utils==2.2.0
  - pytools==2016.2.6
  - pyyaml==3.12
  - ray==0.3.0
  - redis==2.10.6
  - requests==2.13.0
  - rsa==3.4.2
  - s3transfer==0.1.11
  - style==1.1.0
  - tensorboard-logger==0.0.4
  - tensorflow==1.4.1
  - tensorflow-gpu==1.4.1
  - tensorflow-tensorboard==0.4.0rc3
  - termcolor==1.1.0
  - tf-logger==1.0.2
  - theano==0.9.0
  - torch==1.0.1
  - torch-helpers==0.4.3
  - torchfile==0.1.0
  - torchvision==0.2.0
  - tqdm==4.15.0
  - typing==3.6.4
  - unpyclib==0.8.1
  - update==0.0.1
  - uvloop==0.8.1
  - visdom==0.1.7
  - waterbear==2.5.0
  - zmq==0.0.0
prefix: /home/kong/anaconda3/envs/tf14
```

I keep getting different ResolvePackageNotFound errors everytime I run the command `conda env create -f tf14.yml`

Run 1:

```
ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - expat==2.1.0=0
  - ipython_genutils==0.1.0=py35_0
  - libxml2==2.9.2=0
  - pandas==0.20.1=np112py35_0
  - icu==54.1=0
  - pygments==2.1.3=py35_0
  - libgpuarray==0.6.2=0
  - pbr==1.10.0=py35_0
  - openblas==0.2.19=0
  - entrypoints==0.2.2=py35_0
  - pyzmq==15.4.0=py35_0
  - numexpr==2.6.2=np112py35_nomkl_0
  - mock==2.0.0=py35_0
  - jsonschema==2.5.1=py35_0
  - numba==0.31.0=np112py35_0
  - tk==8.5.18=0
  - flask==0.11.1=py35_0
  - pyqt==5.6.0=py35_2
  - ipython==5.1.0=py35_0
  - pygpu==0.6.2=py35_0
  - jupyter_core==4.2.0=py35_0
  - libpng==1.6.27=0
  - ptyprocess==0.5.1=py35_0
  - itsdangerous==0.24=py35_0
  - libiconv==1.14=0
  - h5py==2.7.0=np112py35_0
  - pip==9.0.1=py35_1
  - wcwidth==0.1.7=py35_0
  - numpy==1.12.1=py35_nomkl_0
  - qt==5.6.2=5
  - olefile==0.44=py35_0
  - python-dateutil==2.5.3=py35_0
  - scikit-learn==0.18.1=np112py35_nomkl_1
  - cffi==1.10.0=py35_0
  - pexpect==4.0.1=py35_0
  - mako==1.0.4=py35_0
  - dbus==1.10.10=0
  - libxcb==1.12=0
  - libsodium==1.0.10=0
  - llvmlite==0.16.0=py35_0
  - libtiff==4.0.6=3
  - zlib==1.2.8=3
  - prompt_toolkit==1.0.3=py35_0
  - libffi==3.2.1=0
  - simplegeneric==0.8.1=py35_1
  - matplotlib==2.0.2=np112py35_0
  - readline==6.2=2
  - nomkl==1.0=0
  - decorator==4.0.10=py35_0
  - freetype==2.5.5=1
  - jinja2==2.8=py35_1
  - jpeg==9b=0
  - path.py==8.2.1=py35_0
  - openssl==1.0.2j=0
  - gst-plugins-base==1.8.0=0
  - jbig==2.1=0
  - cycler==0.10.0=py35_0
  - setuptools==27.2.0=py35_0
  - networkx==1.11=py35_0
  - six==1.10.0=py35_0
  - sqlite==3.13.0=0
  - nbconvert==4.2.0=py35_0
  - xz==5.2.2=0
  - seaborn==0.7.1=py35_0
  - pycparser==2.18=py35_0
  - scipy==0.19.0=np112py35_nomkl_0
  - traitlets==4.3.1=py35_0
  - mkl-service==1.1.2=py35_3
  - libgfortran==3.0.0=1
  - werkzeug==0.11.11=py35_0
  - fontconfig==2.12.1=3
  - terminado==0.6=py35_0
  - libgcc==5.2.0=0
  - wheel==0.29.0=py35_0
  - nbformat==4.1.0=py35_0
  - markupsafe==0.23=py35_2
  - pyparsing==2.1.4=py35_0
  - python==3.5.2=0
  - jupyter_client==4.4.0=py35_0
  - pytz==2016.7=py35_0
  - mistune==0.7.3=py35_0
  - pickleshare==0.7.4=py35_0
  - tornado==4.4.2=py35_0
  - notebook==4.2.3=py35_0
  - pillow==4.2.1=py35_0
  - hdf5==1.8.17=1
  - sip==4.18=py35_0
  - gstreamer==1.8.0=0
  - mkl==2017.0.1=0
  - ipykernel==4.5.0=py35_0
  - boto==2.48.0=py35_0
  - glib==2.43.0=1
  - zeromq==4.1.4=0
```

Run 2:

```
ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - entrypoints==0.2.2=py35_0
  - xz==5.2.2=0
  - sqlite==3.13.0=0
  - boto==2.48.0=py35_0
  - itsdangerous==0.24=py35_0
  - flask==0.11.1=py35_0
  - zeromq==4.1.4=0
  - cycler==0.10.0=py35_0
  - decorator==4.0.10=py35_0
  - openssl==1.0.2j=0
  - prompt_toolkit==1.0.3=py35_0
  - tk==8.5.18=0
  - notebook==4.2.3=py35_0
  - ipython==5.1.0=py35_0
  - jinja2==2.8=py35_1
  - libtiff==4.0.6=3
  - dbus==1.10.10=0
  - numba==0.31.0=np112py35_0
  - h5py==2.7.0=np112py35_0
  - jpeg==9b=0
  - seaborn==0.7.1=py35_0
  - zlib==1.2.8=3
  - terminado==0.6=py35_0
  - fontconfig==2.12.1=3
  - pip==9.0.1=py35_1
  - numpy==1.12.1=py35_nomkl_0
  - simplegeneric==0.8.1=py35_1
  - olefile==0.44=py35_0
  - libgcc==5.2.0=0
  - mako==1.0.4=py35_0
  - six==1.10.0=py35_0
  - gstreamer==1.8.0=0
  - libiconv==1.14=0
  - mock==2.0.0=py35_0
  - llvmlite==0.16.0=py35_0
  - libgfortran==3.0.0=1
  - jbig==2.1=0
  - jupyter_core==4.2.0=py35_0
  - glib==2.43.0=1
  - expat==2.1.0=0
  - pillow==4.2.1=py35_0
  - libgpuarray==0.6.2=0
  - ipython_genutils==0.1.0=py35_0
  - qt==5.6.2=5
  - pycparser==2.18=py35_0
  - pyzmq==15.4.0=py35_0
  - markupsafe==0.23=py35_2
  - cffi==1.10.0=py35_0
  - mkl==2017.0.1=0
  - pickleshare==0.7.4=py35_0
  - pbr==1.10.0=py35_0
  - libxcb==1.12=0
  - libffi==3.2.1=0
  - mkl-service==1.1.2=py35_3
  - nbformat==4.1.0=py35_0
  - libxml2==2.9.2=0
  - matplotlib==2.0.2=np112py35_0
  - gst-plugins-base==1.8.0=0
  - pexpect==4.0.1=py35_0
  - pyparsing==2.1.4=py35_0
  - scikit-learn==0.18.1=np112py35_nomkl_1
  - sip==4.18=py35_0
  - tornado==4.4.2=py35_0
  - networkx==1.11=py35_0
  - readline==6.2=2
  - pandas==0.20.1=np112py35_0
  - libsodium==1.0.10=0
  - openblas==0.2.19=0
  - libpng==1.6.27=0
  - pygpu==0.6.2=py35_0
  - nbconvert==4.2.0=py35_0
  - scipy==0.19.0=np112py35_nomkl_0
  - hdf5==1.8.17=1
  - numexpr==2.6.2=np112py35_nomkl_0
  - jupyter_client==4.4.0=py35_0
  - mistune==0.7.3=py35_0
  - nomkl==1.0=0
  - path.py==8.2.1=py35_0
  - wheel==0.29.0=py35_0
  - icu==54.1=0
  - pyqt==5.6.0=py35_2
  - setuptools==27.2.0=py35_0
  - jsonschema==2.5.1=py35_0
  - wcwidth==0.1.7=py35_0
  - ptyprocess==0.5.1=py35_0
  - ipykernel==4.5.0=py35_0
  - freetype==2.5.5=1
  - python-dateutil==2.5.3=py35_0
  - python==3.5.2=0
  - pygments==2.1.3=py35_0
  - werkzeug==0.11.11=py35_0
  - pytz==2016.7=py35_0
  - traitlets==4.3.1=py35_0
```

Run 3:

```
ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - decorator==4.0.10=py35_0
  - simplegeneric==0.8.1=py35_1
  - scikit-learn==0.18.1=np112py35_nomkl_1
  - mako==1.0.4=py35_0
  - flask==0.11.1=py35_0
  - pyparsing==2.1.4=py35_0
  - tk==8.5.18=0
  - pexpect==4.0.1=py35_0
  - dbus==1.10.10=0
  - pytz==2016.7=py35_0
  - hdf5==1.8.17=1
  - nomkl==1.0=0
  - xz==5.2.2=0
  - openblas==0.2.19=0
  - pyqt==5.6.0=py35_2
  - libgfortran==3.0.0=1
  - libiconv==1.14=0
  - prompt_toolkit==1.0.3=py35_0
  - libgpuarray==0.6.2=0
  - libgcc==5.2.0=0
  - pbr==1.10.0=py35_0
  - zeromq==4.1.4=0
  - jupyter_core==4.2.0=py35_0
  - notebook==4.2.3=py35_0
  - jsonschema==2.5.1=py35_0
  - icu==54.1=0
  - gst-plugins-base==1.8.0=0
  - pygpu==0.6.2=py35_0
  - mkl-service==1.1.2=py35_3
  - ptyprocess==0.5.1=py35_0
  - pip==9.0.1=py35_1
  - ipykernel==4.5.0=py35_0
  - pyzmq==15.4.0=py35_0
  - traitlets==4.3.1=py35_0
  - numba==0.31.0=np112py35_0
  - pickleshare==0.7.4=py35_0
  - wheel==0.29.0=py35_0
  - setuptools==27.2.0=py35_0
  - olefile==0.44=py35_0
  - cycler==0.10.0=py35_0
  - gstreamer==1.8.0=0
  - ipython==5.1.0=py35_0
  - jbig==2.1=0
  - cffi==1.10.0=py35_0
  - tornado==4.4.2=py35_0
  - libxcb==1.12=0
  - six==1.10.0=py35_0
  - sip==4.18=py35_0
  - scipy==0.19.0=np112py35_nomkl_0
  - qt==5.6.2=5
  - numpy==1.12.1=py35_nomkl_0
  - libffi==3.2.1=0
  - llvmlite==0.16.0=py35_0
  - itsdangerous==0.24=py35_0
  - pandas==0.20.1=np112py35_0
  - libsodium==1.0.10=0
  - readline==6.2=2
  - nbformat==4.1.0=py35_0
  - jupyter_client==4.4.0=py35_0
  - mkl==2017.0.1=0
  - werkzeug==0.11.11=py35_0
  - nbconvert==4.2.0=py35_0
  - fontconfig==2.12.1=3
  - zlib==1.2.8=3
  - wcwidth==0.1.7=py35_0
  - jpeg==9b=0
  - freetype==2.5.5=1
  - openssl==1.0.2j=0
  - pillow==4.2.1=py35_0
  - sqlite==3.13.0=0
  - boto==2.48.0=py35_0
  - mistune==0.7.3=py35_0
  - mock==2.0.0=py35_0
  - numexpr==2.6.2=np112py35_nomkl_0
  - h5py==2.7.0=np112py35_0
  - entrypoints==0.2.2=py35_0
  - terminado==0.6=py35_0
  - glib==2.43.0=1
  - libpng==1.6.27=0
  - libxml2==2.9.2=0
  - networkx==1.11=py35_0
  - seaborn==0.7.1=py35_0
  - pygments==2.1.3=py35_0
  - libtiff==4.0.6=3
  - pycparser==2.18=py35_0
  - jinja2==2.8=py35_1
  - markupsafe==0.23=py35_2
  - ipython_genutils==0.1.0=py35_0
  - python-dateutil==2.5.3=py35_0
  - python==3.5.2=0
  - matplotlib==2.0.2=np112py35_0
  - expat==2.1.0=0
  - path.py==8.2.1=py35_0
```

Run 4:

```
ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - llvmlite==0.16.0=py35_0
  - freetype==2.5.5=1
  - libiconv==1.14=0
  - jinja2==2.8=py35_1
  - matplotlib==2.0.2=np112py35_0
  - libgpuarray==0.6.2=0
  - networkx==1.11=py35_0
  - ptyprocess==0.5.1=py35_0
  - libxcb==1.12=0
  - cycler==0.10.0=py35_0
  - terminado==0.6=py35_0
  - wheel==0.29.0=py35_0
  - pickleshare==0.7.4=py35_0
  - openssl==1.0.2j=0
  - scipy==0.19.0=np112py35_nomkl_0
  - pillow==4.2.1=py35_0
  - numba==0.31.0=np112py35_0
  - python-dateutil==2.5.3=py35_0
  - numpy==1.12.1=py35_nomkl_0
  - libtiff==4.0.6=3
  - readline==6.2=2
  - tornado==4.4.2=py35_0
  - python==3.5.2=0
  - jupyter_client==4.4.0=py35_0
  - markupsafe==0.23=py35_2
  - libgfortran==3.0.0=1
  - sqlite==3.13.0=0
  - h5py==2.7.0=np112py35_0
  - jupyter_core==4.2.0=py35_0
  - libsodium==1.0.10=0
  - pyzmq==15.4.0=py35_0
  - jsonschema==2.5.1=py35_0
  - zlib==1.2.8=3
  - icu==54.1=0
  - simplegeneric==0.8.1=py35_1
  - mkl==2017.0.1=0
  - cffi==1.10.0=py35_0
  - six==1.10.0=py35_0
  - hdf5==1.8.17=1
  - sip==4.18=py35_0
  - libpng==1.6.27=0
  - seaborn==0.7.1=py35_0
  - ipykernel==4.5.0=py35_0
  - pyqt==5.6.0=py35_2
  - glib==2.43.0=1
  - pbr==1.10.0=py35_0
  - zeromq==4.1.4=0
  - pygments==2.1.3=py35_0
  - mock==2.0.0=py35_0
  - boto==2.48.0=py35_0
  - decorator==4.0.10=py35_0
  - setuptools==27.2.0=py35_0
  - libgcc==5.2.0=0
  - xz==5.2.2=0
  - dbus==1.10.10=0
  - pexpect==4.0.1=py35_0
  - qt==5.6.2=5
  - itsdangerous==0.24=py35_0
  - path.py==8.2.1=py35_0
  - mistune==0.7.3=py35_0
  - nbconvert==4.2.0=py35_0
  - tk==8.5.18=0
  - expat==2.1.0=0
  - jpeg==9b=0
  - pip==9.0.1=py35_1
  - pygpu==0.6.2=py35_0
  - gstreamer==1.8.0=0
  - entrypoints==0.2.2=py35_0
  - traitlets==4.3.1=py35_0
  - jbig==2.1=0
  - openblas==0.2.19=0
  - notebook==4.2.3=py35_0
  - fontconfig==2.12.1=3
  - pytz==2016.7=py35_0
  - wcwidth==0.1.7=py35_0
  - nomkl==1.0=0
  - libffi==3.2.1=0
  - mkl-service==1.1.2=py35_3
  - pandas==0.20.1=np112py35_0
  - nbformat==4.1.0=py35_0
  - werkzeug==0.11.11=py35_0
  - ipython==5.1.0=py35_0
  - gst-plugins-base==1.8.0=0
  - olefile==0.44=py35_0
  - ipython_genutils==0.1.0=py35_0
  - pyparsing==2.1.4=py35_0
  - libxml2==2.9.2=0
  - pycparser==2.18=py35_0
  - scikit-learn==0.18.1=np112py35_nomkl_1
  - numexpr==2.6.2=np112py35_nomkl_0
  - flask==0.11.1=py35_0
  - prompt_toolkit==1.0.3=py35_0
  - mako==1.0.4=py35_0
```

And it goes on. How do I fix this? The solution posted at [ResolvePackageNotFound: Create env using conda and yml file on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49154899/resolvepackagenotfound-create-env-using-conda-and-yml-file-on-macos/58160918) does not work here because the error message keeps changing.

Comment: Python 3.5 has been EOL for over a year, and this project looks like it hasn't been updated.  It also looks like this file is pulling from some esoteric channels, whereas most things should be available from i.e. `conda-forge`

Comment: If you **must** use this environment, you'll probably need to remove the pins to patch versions, which the solver tends to choke on. For example, `   - matplotlib==2.0.2=np112py35_0` points to one specific build of one specific version of that package, which is an extremely brittle starting condition. `- matplotlib==2.0`, and making the same change everywhere, would likely get **a** solution.

Comment: @MattThompson note that the project does not require Conda Forge, and the use of build strings is probably a good thing here (helps identify channel of origin). Including **free** channel, plus `channel_priority: flexible` is sufficient to get the Conda part to solve in a reasonable time.

Answer (score 0):

This seems less of a Conda problem: all Conda packages will install once **free** channel is added, and `channel_priority` is set to flexible. See [this environment creation in GitHub Actions](https://github.com/mfansler/conda-envs-testing/actions/workflows/causal-infogan.yaml).

Instead, what is more problematic is that PyPI appears to have removed the `pprint` package, which is not only explicitly specified in the `pip:` section, but is required by multiple packages also in that section ([see related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63457762/570918)). Unless there is a container out there that captured this environment or you can get ahold of one of the `pprint` tarballs, I don't see much hope in getting this environment recreated.